# Query that returns rows that have both values in an IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation, having

I am trying to write a query that returns all the rows that have both values of an IN clause in the table and they share a common order #

For example I have

```
SELECT order_num, order_type
  FROM order_table
 WHERE order_type IN ('update','create')
   AND order_num('1234');
```

This works with a single input of `1234` as `the order num`, I am struggling to write a query that doesn't need input but returns all orders that have both an update and a create.

I was trying to write a subquery on the same table but wasn't sure if that is best practice or not.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need grouping with `having` clause

```
SELECT order_num
  FROM order_table
 WHERE order_type IN ('update','create')
 GROUP BY order_num
HAVING count(distinct order_type)=2
```

Comment: I think this would work but I realized when a new record is written with 'update' the order_num changes from '1234' to '1234c' so I have to get substring to work with it before I can confirm this will work though. Does Group by allow multiple columns in select though?

Comment: @RanchDubois if this s a fixed rule, I mean occur for every cases, then you can consider `SELECT rtrim(order_num,'c') as order_num .... GROUP BY rtrim(order_num,'c') .....`. No, non-aggregated columns in the select-list are allowed  as long as they're included in the group by part.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to join to order_table once for the 'create' set and once for the 'update' set and then join them.

assuming your creates don't have the c while the updates do...

```
SELECT a.order_num, a.order_type, b.order_num, b.order_type 
FROM order_table a
INNER JOIN order_table b
   on a.order_num &'c' = B.order_num
  and a.order_Type ='create'
  and b.order_Type ='update'
```

Function based indexe on order-num when type is create and indexes on order_type/Order_num would likely help w/ performance if it's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest of all is to use EXISTS:

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(OUTT.ORDER_NUM, 'c'),
    OUTT.ORDER_TYPE
FROM
    ORDER_TABLE OUTT
WHERE
    OUTT.ORDER_TYPE = 'update'
    AND OUTT.ORDER_NUM IN (
        '1234'
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            ORDER_TABLE INN
        WHERE
            RTRIM(OUTT.ORDER_NUM, 'c') = RTRIM(INN.ORDER_NUM, 'c')
            AND INN.ORDER_TYPE = 'create'
    );
```